# ASP.Net MVC template or CMS for paid subscriptions to webapp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subscription

I'm searching for a way to easily create a subscription system for a MVC webapp

- User registers (confirm e-mail)
- User purchases subscription type (a license to use protected areas of the webapp)
- Payment system
- License renewal methods (when the year is up and license is not revoked, a new one is created and the user is billed)

I have not found any MVC templates or CMS systems that can do this. Best I have found is Joomla! with a bunch of extensions I can choose from that can do the above, if it weren't for the fact that it is written in PHP and hasn't got a build in SOAP service.

So, any ideas?

Comment: `So, any ideas?` => here's an idea that might sound foolish to you: you could develop one by, you know, writing some code.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, of course I could do that, but I this sounds like such a commonly used system that they should be out there no?